# How to integrate Active Directory in VisualSVN Server

Tags: active-directory, svn, visualsvn-server

I'm using the VisualSVN Server Standard Edition.

Is it possible to integrate Active Directory in VisualSVN Server with this version?

If it's possible, how to do that?

I researched a lot via google but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I would really appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 4):

Possible but only with the Basic authentication protocol.

It is listed [here](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/) that the Enterprise edition allows the use of Windows Integrated Authentication (Kerberos, NTLM).

A little [information](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) on Basic authentication:

> **Basic authentication**
>
> Basic authentication is part of the HTTP 1.0 specification. With Basic Windows Authentication users are requested to re-enter their Windows username and password to the Subversion client. Username and passwords are then transmitted across HTTP(S) protocol in plain text. These credentials are then verified by VisualSVN Server.
>   Despite its simplicity, Basic windows authentication has obvious limitations:
>
> **Security weaknesses.** Passwords are transmitted in plain text making them vulnerable if intercepted. Passwords are also cached on disk which provides another opportunity for unwanted access.
>
> **Additional authentication step.** Despite being authenticated by their Windows user credentials, users must still re-enter their username and password to access VisualSVN Server.
>
> **Incompatible with smart cards.** Since users are always requested to provide their username and password, Basic authentication method is inherently incompatible with two-factor authentication systems.
>
> When security is important, Basic authentication should be never used across the unsecure HTTP protocol because users' credentials are easy to intercept and access. Basic authentication across an SSL connection provides an adequate level of security so for small business users, Basic authentication combined with SSL is sufficient.